# GEE Python API: Mapping a function across ee.List and ee,ImageCollection

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, toa-calibration

I have a function that I would like to map across an `ee.List`, and map it over an `ee.ImageCollection of raw DN images`.

So far it is looking like (using wrapper functions):

```
def perturb_image(pert_matrix):
    #'''
    #pert_matrix is fed as an ee.List()
    #'''
  
  def toa_reflectance(image):
      #'''
      #:params
      #  - ee.Image (raw)
      #  - list of  mult coefficients (regular list)
      #  -  bias list (ee.List)
      #    returns TOA image
      #''' 

        band1 = image.select("B1")   ... etc.    
        toa_1 = band1.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(0)).multiply(row[0])).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(0))).multiply(ee.Number(constant)) ... etc.
        toa = ee.Image.cat([toa_1, toa_2, toa_3, toa_4, toa_5, toa_6, toa_7, toa_9, bqa])

        return toa
return toa_reflectance
```

I tried implementing them in the following way:

```
images = ee.ImageCollection
mat = ee.List([ * insert list of perturbed gain factors * ])

images_new = images.map(mat.map(perturb_image)) #ee.ImageCollection
```

I receive errors such as "`AttributeError: 'ComputedObject' object has no attribute 'get'`"

I have also tried to instead map the function only over the `ee.List`, and applied to a single image.     `mat.map(perturb_image())(image)`

, but that has only yielded: `TypeError: perturb_image() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pert_matrix'`.

Wondering if it is a casting issue?

(Edited after Kevin Reid's answer):

```
def perturb_image(pert_matrix):
  pert_matrix = ee.List(pert_matrix)
  
  def row_perturb(row): #this should be mapped to pert_matrix 
    row = ee.List(row)

    def toa_reflectance(image): #should be innermost
        #'''
        #:params
        #  - ee.Image (raw)
        #  - list of  mult coefficients (regular list)
        #  -  bias list (ee.List)
        #returns TOA image
        #'''
        #ee.Array(refmult_list).multiply(ee.Array(pert_array)).toList()
        mult_list = ee.List(image.get('REF_MULTS_BANDS[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]'))
        add_list = ee.List(image.get('REF_ADDS_BANDS[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]'))
        sun_ang = ee.Number(image.get('SUN_ELEVATION'))
        sine_val = ee.Number(sun_ang.multiply(math.pi).divide(180).sin())#radians
        constant = ee.Number(1).divide(sine_val)
        #now for the bands
        band1 = image.select("B1")
        band2 = image.select("B2")
        band3 = image.select("B3")
        band4 = image.select("B4")
        band5 = image.select("B5")
        band6 = image.select("B6")
        band7 = image.select("B7")
        band9 = image.select("B9")
        bqa   = image.select("BQA")
      
        band_list = ee.List([band1, band2, band3, band4, band5, band6, band7, band9])
        
        toa_1 = band1.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(0)).multiply(row.get(0))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(0))).multiply(ee.Number(constant))  
        toa_2 = band2.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(1)).multiply(row.get(1))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(1))).multiply(ee.Number(constant))
        toa_3 = band3.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(2)).multiply(row.get(2))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(2))).multiply(ee.Number(constant))
        toa_4 = band4.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(3)).multiply(row.get(3))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(3))).multiply(ee.Number(constant))      
        toa_5 = band5.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(4)).multiply(row.get(4))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(4))).multiply(ee.Number(constant))
        toa_6 = band6.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(5)).multiply(row.get(5))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(5))).multiply(ee.Number(constant))
        toa_7 = band7.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(6)).multiply(row.get(6))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(6))).multiply(ee.Number(constant))
        toa_9 = band9.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(7)).multiply(row.get(7))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(7))).multiply(ee.Number(constant))

        toa = ee.Image.cat([toa_1, toa_2, toa_3, toa_4, toa_5, toa_6, toa_7, toa_9, bqa])
        
        return toa
    return toa_reflectance
  return pert_matrix.map(row_perturb) #this returns a... function?

mat = ee.List([[0.99, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.991, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.992, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.993, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.994, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.995, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.996, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.997, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.998, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0.999, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.001, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.0019999999999998, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.0029999999999997, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.0039999999999996, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.0049999999999994, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.0059999999999993, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.0069999999999992, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.0079999999999991, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.008999999999999, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.009999999999999, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])



#toa_thing = ee.ImageCollection(*list of images*)

images_new = toa_thing.map(perturb_image(mat))
print(images_new.getInfo())
```

When I call the function as above, I receive the following error: `EEException: Can't encode object: <function perturb_image.<locals>.row_perturb.<locals>.toa_reflectance at 0x7fd56557b268>`

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes, if you have a missing method like `'get'`, you likely need to write a cast inside the mapped function. However, there are bigger problems here.

- `mat.map(perturb_image)`: given that `mat` is an `ee.List`, this will produce another `ee.List`. But the return value of `perturb_image` is a Python function, which can't be stored by itself in an `ee.List`.
- `images.map(mat.map(perturb_image))`: Now you're taking that `ee.List` (if it could exist) and passing it *as the mapping function* to `ImageCollection.map`. This will not work, because a list is not a function.
- `mat.map(perturb_image())(image)`: This fails straightforwardly because you're immediately *calling* `perturb_image` with zero arguments, when it expects one.

Based on the comment that `perturb_image` takes a matrix, I suspect that what you're actually trying to do is just *apply* `perturb_image` to get a mapping function. In that case, to do it with the collection is:

```py
images_new = images.map(perturb_image(mat))
```

Or for one image:

```py
image_new = perturb_image(mat)(image)
```

When you're just calling a function you defined, once, there is no `map` in it — you write it just like you would in plain Python.

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin! I wanted to clarify— if perturb_matrix is a list of lists (ex: ee.List([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]) and I wanted to do a procedure for each *row* of this list, should I still need to map the function across perturb_matrix somewhere in the nested function?

Comment: @sbab Yes, that's correct.